# Executable 'ffmpeg' not found in python

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm trying to compress a video using python but there is an error that I can't understand how to solve it, so can you help me please ?
I have attached an image and the code [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OiFT.png)

```
import ffmpy

input_name = input("Enter name of input file: ")
crf = int(input("Enter constant rate factor between 18 and 24: "))
output_name = input("Enter output file name: ")
inp = {input_name: None}
outp = {output_name: '-vcodec libx264 -crf %d'%crf}     #video  codec and compression rate
ff = ffmpy.FFmpeg(inputs=inp, outputs=outp)             #creates an FFmpeg object
print(ff.cmd)                                           #just to verify that it produces the correct ffmpeg command
ff.run()                                                #does the compression
print("done!")
```

Running, I get

```
Enter name of input file: newproject.mp4
Enter constant rate factor between 18 and 24: 20
Enter output file name: "com.mp4"
ffmpeg -i newproject.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 com.mp4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/ahmed/Installed Programs/PyCharm/SelecedTopics/bonus2.py", line 10, in <module>
    ff.run()                                                #does the compression
  File "E:\ahmed\Python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\ffmpy.py", line 99, in run
    raise FFExecutableNotFoundError("Executable '{0}' not found".format(self.executable))
ffmpy.FFExecutableNotFoundError: Executable 'ffmpeg' not found

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Obvious question, do you have ffmpeg installed on your machine?

Comment: `ffmpy` is just a wrapper for calling the ffmpeg program.

Comment: I have only installed ffmpy using pip install ffmpy on the anaconda cmd. how can I install ffmpeg ?

Comment: probably a little late but here it is https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

Answer (score 2):

One of the package dependencies of `ffmpy` is `ffmpeg`. In fact `ffmpy` is a wrapper for `ffmpeg`. To fix your issue use pip to install `ffmpeg`.